# My page is not scrollable on the dev environment, but scrollable on the production

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I have issue with the scrolling bar when I open a table, or something else, with overflowing content. I can see the scroll bar on the right, because there is a style on the html: `overflow-y: scroll;`. However, on my test environment, when I load 50-100 devices, the table becomes larger, but the scroller on the right still remain in gray and I am unable to scroll down. On the other side, on my production environment, the scroll bar is working as expected. I am unable to understand what is causing the issue, as I did not make any style changes on the html, body or the table components itself. Here is a picture of what I see on the test environment:
[image]

Now, you can see the table in the 'prod' environment:
[image]

I tried by disabling the overflow on the html at all and enable the `overflow-y: auto;` on the body, but then the `LOGOUT` button will remain somewhere in the middle on the left-side navigation when I scroll down to to bottom. However, I know the best solution might be to set a `vh` height on the table and set overflow to it, but then, my pagination will have to go on a custom separate html and now it is just pre-build from the vuetify library. Additionally, my goal is to find what is causing this, since there was no change on the styling for the html, body, the tables or any other component that I can think might be related to this.

Here is my code:

```js
<template>
    <v-card>
        <remove-dialog ref="removeDialog" @refresh="fetchDevices"></remove-dialog>
        <add-dialog ref="addDialog" @refresh="fetchDevices"></add-dialog>

        <v-card-title class="mb-4">
            <v-btn color="success" @click="addDevice" outlined small>
                <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
                {{ $t('action.addNew') }}
            </v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <div>{{ `You have ${devicesLeft} available devices to make ` }}</div>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-text-field
                class="pa-0"
                v-model="search"
                @change="fetchDevices"
                append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                :label="$t('label.search')"
                single-line
                hide-details
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="devices"
            :options.sync="options"
            :server-items-length="totalDevices"
            :loading="isLoading"
            :footer-props="footerOptions"
            :no-results-text="$t('noDataAvailable')"
            :no-data-text="$t('noDataAvailable')"
        >
            <template v-slot:[`item.connectedItems`]="{ item }">
                <a @click="goToConnectedItems(item.connectedItems)">{{ item.connectedItems.length }}</a>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:[`item.lastConnection`]="{ item }">
                <span v-if="item.lastConnection">{{ item.lastConnection | moment('from', 'now') }}</span>
                <span v-else>n/a</span>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
                <v-tooltip top>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" @click="editDevice(item)" icon>
                            <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <span>{{ $t('action.edit') }}</span>
                </v-tooltip>
                <v-tooltip top>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn color="error" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" @click="removeDevice(item)" icon>
                            <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <span>{{ $t('action.delete') }}</span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

There is not styling part for this component.

Answer (score 0):

I started to back-test the features that I've implement and I have found what is causing this issue - the Ionic and its css styling. Since I am using some ionic components, just for an dialog preview, I injected it as follows:

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
```

The `ionic.bundle.css` is setting the body overflow to hidden and that is why the scroll is not enabling. Then, I decided to try injecting this css to the exact component where I am using the ionic components with `<style scoped>`, however, for some reason it still was setting the style to the body element. Thus, I decided to find out which styling exactly is screwing up my page.

Since the `bundle` is loading a bunch of styles, I decided to add the ionic css files separately and started with the mandatory one - `core.css`. Then, I decided to add some other optional stylings, because the text of my ionic components was not using the exact font as expected. I added `normalize.css`, `structure.css` and `typography.css` one by one, and concluded that exactly the `structure.css` is setting the `overflow: hidden` to my body element. Therefore, I ended up with the following injects (my scroll was working and my font was exactly what I needed):

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/typography.css" />
```

#ionic #ionic-vue